# Convertir binario de 32 bits a real

Tags: python, numpy

Resulta que debo convertir el binario dado con las siguientes fórmulas, usando producto punto para las sumatorias.

- Fórmulas extraídas de aquí: 
  [Computer Arithmetics and Round-off Methods - GitHub - sbustamante/ComputationalMethods](https://github.com/sbustamante/ComputationalMethods/blob/2379473ea5a10a7938c6333a70fe8b859472cea8/material/.ipynb_checkpoints/computer-arithmetics-checkpoint.ipynb)

[image: Fórmulas]

Diseñé este código:

```
import numpy as np

#Creamos el arreglo bs que me separa individualmente los elementos del string
bs=np.array(list('00111110001000000000000000000000'))

#el comando b.astype covierte los elemento de la lista a enteros
bs=bs.astype(int)

#Invertimos el arreglo así es más fácil implementar la fórmula
sb=bs[::-1]

#Tomamos ciertos segmentos del arreglo:
#s es el correspondiente al signo,
#e es el correspondiente al exponente,
#f es el correspondiente a la fracción.

s=sb[31:32]
f=sb[:23]
e=sb[23:31]

#Creamos la variable 'fe' que es la correspondiente a los primeros 8 términos del arreglo
#y así pues hallamos el producto punto tras hallar el término 2^i

fe=sb[:8]
ep = np.exp2(fe)

#'exp' es el resultado correspondiente a la sumatoria del exponente
exp=np.dot(e,np.exp2(fe))

#Creamos 'ff' puesto que el término de la sumatoria me decrece, lo que equivale a usar la cadena original
#Además es necesario crar otro arreglo que vaya desde i=1 hasta i=23 para eso creamos 'ff2'
#también creamos la variable 'efra' que es 1/'ff2' aplicándole exponencial puesto que así respetamos el signo
ff=f[::-1]
ff2=sb[1:24]
efra= 1./(np.exp2(ff2))

#'frac' es el producto punto que equivale a la sumatoria
frac=np.dot(ff,efra)

#Ahora pues, llamemos 'r' el real que buscamos y apliquemos la fórmula

r=((-1)**s)*(1+frac)*2**(exp-127)

print (r)
```

Al final el número me da del orden de `e-37` y debe dar `0.15625`.

Answer (score 1):

El principal error esta en la conversion de los bits a enteros o doubles.

he creado una funcion que convierte los bits invertidos a su valor entero correspondiente, en el caso del exponente se puede usar directamente, pero en el caso de la mantisa se puede usar lo mismo pero multiplicado por 2**-23, obteniendo lo siguiente:

```
import numpy as np

def list_to_int(l):
    return np.dot(l,np.exp2(np.arange(len(l))))

#Creamos el arreglo bs que me separa individualmente los elementos del string
bs=np.array(list('00111110001000000000000000000000'))

#el comando b.astype covierte los elemento de la lista a enteros
bs=bs.astype(int)
sb = bs[::-1]

s=sb[-1]
f=sb[:23]
e=sb[23:31]

exponent = list_to_int(e)
mantissa = list_to_int(f)*np.exp2(-len(f))
val = ((-1)**s)*(1+mantissa)*np.exp2(exponent-127)
print(val)
```

Output:

```
0.15625
```